# Split an Apple-supplied Fusion Drive back into two separate volumes?

Tags: macos, encryption, core-storage, fusion-drive

Is it possible to take an Apple factory-created [Fusion Drive](http://www.apple.com/imac/performance/#fusion) and downgrade it into two separate volumes?  I understand this would also necessitate reinstalling the OS and Recovery Partition etc.

The reason to do so is that the company-mandated [Sophos SafeGuard](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/encryption/safeguard-enterprise.aspx) disk encryption software won't work on a Fusion Drive (unsurprisingly), and FileVault 2 is prohibited (for now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can split up a Fusion drive:

http://www.macworld.com/article/2015664/how-to-split-up-a-fusion-drive.html